# When `User` is struct, what is `(*User)(nil)`?

Tags: go, pointers, type-conversion

This compiles:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    ID int64
}

func main() {
    v := (*User)(nil)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Here, what is `(*User)(nil)`?
I encountered this notation at [go-pg](https://pg.uptrace.dev/), and had no clue to find an answer because it was very hard to search on google.

Comment: It's equivalent to `var v *User`, not sure why they used this specific notation, since `nil` is always the zero value of a pointer.

Comment: It's a common technique used to convey a type - typically for reflection purposes - without incurring the overhead of creating a variable of that type.

Comment: doesn't this have exactly the same performance implications as `var v *User` ?

Comment: Ah yet another reason to avoid go-pg :0) use GORM instead.

Comment: @DanielFarrell it saves one line of code :)

Comment: @colm.anseo: except that it doesn't save any lines, because `var v *User` declares `v` and sets `v` to `nil`, which takes one line, and `v := (*User)(nil)` declares `v` and sets `v` to `nil`, which takes ... one line.

Comment: @torek I was referring to the reflect one-liner usage: https://play.golang.org/p/WfCMo25RXlE

Comment: @colm.anseo Oh - yes, I skipped right over the intermediate comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `User` is a [type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), `*User` is another type, a [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types), a pointer to `User`.

`(*User)(nil)` is a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions): it converts the untyped `nil` predeclared identifier to `(*User)`. You must put `*User` into parenthesis, else the expression would try to convert `nil` to `User` (which is a compile-time error if `User` is a struct), and then dereference it.

So `v` will be a variable of type `*User`, holding the `nil` pointer value.

The `v := (*User)(nil)` expression is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) and it is equivalent (shorthand) to the following [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

```
var v *User = nil
```

Which is of course the same as

```
var v *User
```

Because if the initialization expression is missing, the variable will be initialized to its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) which is `nil` for all pointer types.